# SQL Server 2014 nchar convert to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I posted a few weeks ago and I am still having problems. I am completely lost with dates. I am trying to pull Monday to Friday for the previous week (whatever day I run the report on current week, I want to be able to see the previous week). The column is stored as `nchar(10)` and when I need to covert it to a `datetime` to be able to look at the previous week, or at least I am almost certain I have to.

I am able to create views and I thought I was doing it right but I getting arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type `datetime` and then it only shows 16 results.

Then after messing around, I am able to get it to pull last week, but it only pulls 10/5/2018 for some reason and no other days.

```
SELECT       
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.i_EmployeeID AS [Employee ID], 
    dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.c_EmployeeFirstName AS [First Name], 
    dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.c_EmployeeLastName AS [Last Name],   
    CAST(dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date AS datetime) AS Date, 
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_AM AS AM, 
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_MD AS MID, 
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_PM AS PM, 
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_LPM AS [Late PM]
FROM           
    dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile ON dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.i_EmployeeID = dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.i_EmployeeID
WHERE        
    (LEFT(dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date, 2) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE() - 1)) 
    AND (RIGHT(dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date, 4) = DATEPART(year,GETDATE() - 1)) 
    AND (SUBSTRING(dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date, 4, 2) = DATEPART(day, GETDATE() - 4))
```

I think I am almost there, but I have no clue why it is only pulling the 5th of last week and not the other days (10-1 to 10-5). This is currently in a view, I thought that if I made a view I would be able to eliminate the `nchar(10)` column and keep only the `datetime` column since I can't alter the main table. The column in the view has the casted column, but I don't think it is the correct way of doing it.

Any more pointers/guidance would be beyond appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to give us some more information regarding your tbl_DailyBusAssignments data. If the database contains an empty string in that c_Date field, you'll certainly get a lack of matches. Is it possible that someone is using single digits instead of padding with zeros? (E.G. '10/5/2018[SPACE]' instead of '10/05/2018' - NChar will add the spaces.)

Comment: The value is allowed to be null. And yes, it is possible that there could be a space and others won't. It isn't optimized very well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the CONVERT( DATETIME ) method on c_Date as part of the comparison? You should be fine by filtering out the NULLs prior to the CONVERT (or CAST) statement.

Comment: You should store dates with the correct data type. Failing that, convert it to a date (or use `TRY_CONVERT` in cases where you're unsure if they're real dates). Then forget about all the datepart operations and just compare dates to dates (or date ranges). _As far as pulling a single date goes_, your last where clause is literally asking for only days that fall on the day of `GETDATE() - 4` e.g. if you run this on the 9th, it will only pull the 5th. Perhaps reconsider what you're trying to do with the following: `= DATEPART(day, 
GETDATE() - 4))`

Comment: I just now noticed that, I've been working on this for so long I am starting to tunnel. In MySQL I am able to accomplish this using `week (date) = week (current_date) - 1 and YEAR (date) = Year(current_date)` Is there a way that SQL accomplishes this? This is why I am trying to convert the field to a datetime. In MySQL the other data I am pulling is in that datatype so I am not having any issues.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, create a computed column on your table that turns the nchar representation of it into a date. String dates are evil. Also, using table aliases will make your code a lot more legible instead of having to reference the full schema.table.column every time.

Now given the date format you indicated (presumably mm/dd/yyyy) you should be able to accomplish that with `convert(date, MyStringDate, 101`. That magic "101" at the end comes from [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which shows you the codes for different pre-defined date masks.

Second, your query as written has predicates on year month and date (albeit through string manipulation instead of date/time functions), when what you've describe you want is a *range* of dates. One way or another you'll probably need to do something along the lines of `where [MyDate] between [StartOfWeek] and [EndOfWeek]`.

How you determine what those days are, is a question open to some interpretation. One way would simply to say `where datename([MyDate]) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')` although that may perform like garbage depending on your data. You could do something similar with `datepart(week, @MyDate) - 1` as your starting point.

You could also do some clever use of the `dateadd` function to get the lower and upper bounds of the dates you care about. Here's an example of how you could derive such dates. I just generated a list of dates over the past 20 days so you can see what the functions are generating, but you could just as easily start with a single date, and apply similar functions to get specific lower and upper boundaries.:

```
set datefirst 1 -- has the week start on Monday

select
    *,
    OneWeekPrior = dateadd(week, -1, Dt),
    StartOfLastWeek = dateadd(day, -(WkDay - 1), dateadd(week, -1, Dt)),
    EndOfLastWeek = dateadd(day, + (5-WkDay), dateadd(week, -1, dt))
from 
(
    select top 20 Dt = cast(dateadd(day, -row_number() over (order by (select null)), getdate()) as date)
    from sys.all_objects

) a
order by Dt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this might be the direction you want:

```
SELECT
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.i_EmployeeID AS [Employee ID], 
  dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.c_EmployeeFirstName AS [First Name], 
  dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.c_EmployeeLastName AS [Last Name],
  CAST(dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date AS DATETIME) AS [Date], 
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_AM AS AM, 
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_MD AS MID,
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_PM AS PM,
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_LPM AS [Late PM]
FROM
  dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments 
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile
    ON dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.i_EmployeeID = dbo.tbl_EmployeeProfile.i_EmployeeID
WHERE
  ISDATE( dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date ) = 1 AND
  CONVERT( DATETIME, dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date ) >= DATEADD( DAY, 0 - DATEPART( WEEKDAY, GETDATE() ) - 5, GETDATE() ) AND -- Last Monday
  CONVERT( DATETIME, dbo.tbl_DailyBusAssingments.c_Date ) < DATEADD( DAY, 0 - DATEPART( WEEKDAY, GETDATE() ), GETDATE() ) -- Last Saturday
```

Comment: It looks like it is something I am looking at doing, however when I tried your code you posted I get another Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. Which seems like it is telling me that somewhere in the column, something is screwing it up?